# Clear Columns with Button vba

Tags: ms-access, vba

This appears easy but has crushed me into posting this: I need to clear 5 columns with a button click. That's it. I do not need to delete the columns because they are used in a sum calculation. I just need to clear the values greater than zero.

Table Name is Customer

```
Column 1 = Week 1 
Column 2 = Week 2
ETC
```

Here is my garbage code that does not run. Any help would be a great gesture this Holiday season. I am using Access 2016.

```
Private Sub Command80_Click()

    Dim SQL As String

    SQL = "UPDATE Customer " & _
          "SET Week1 = NULL " & _
          "WHERE Week 1 > 0"
DoCmd.RunSQL SQL

End Sub
```

Comment: Worked Like a Champ. Many Thanks you are doing great work.

Answer (score 0):

If the field name to be updated is `Week1` (and not `Week 1`) then this is the code:

```
Private Sub Command80_Click()
    Dim sql As String

    sql = "UPDATE Customer " & _
          "SET Week1 = NULL " & _
          "WHERE Week1 > 0"

    DoCmd.RunSQL sql
End Sub
```

You've used `Week 1` (with a blank) in your code.

Answer (score 0):

If "Week 1" is the actual field name, wrap it in brackets:

```
"SET [Week 1] = NULL " & _
"WHERE [Week 1] > 0"
```